# How use postgres (deadpool-postgres) with WebSocket Actix (actix-web-actors)

Tags: rust, websocket, actix-web

How to use database connection from a WebSocket handler.

It is possible to use `future.into_actor` or `ctx.spawn` or `actix::fut::wrap_future` but that's not accurate :)

In theory, I should not block the ws handler when making a request to the database. Do I need to somehow send the request to some executor in a separate thread?

Didn't find any information or example of using database with websockets.

```rust
type PgPool = deadpool_r2d2::Pool<deadpool_postgres::Manager>;

pub struct MyWebSocket {
    db: deadpool::managed::Object<deadpool_postgres::Manager>    
}

impl MyWebSocket {
    pub fn new(client_db: deadpool::managed::Object<deadpool_postgres::Manager>) -> Self {
        Self { db:client_db }
    }
}

impl Actor for MyWebSocket {
    type Context = ws::WebsocketContext<Self>;
}

impl StreamHandler<Result<ws::Message, ws::ProtocolError>> for MyWebSocket {
    fn handle(&mut self, msg: Result<ws::Message, ws::ProtocolError>, ctx: &mut Self::Context) {
        match msg {
         Ok(ws::Message::Text(text)) => {

             /*
               How used this database?
               Error: only allowed inside `async` functions and blocks**
             */

             let stmt = self.db.prepare_cached("SELECT 1 + $1").await.unwrap();
             let rows = self.db.query(&stmt, &[&3]).await.unwrap();
             let value: i32 = rows[0].get(0);
             ctx.text(format!("{}",value));

         },
         ....
        }
    }
}
fn create_pool(max_size: usize) -> PgPool {
    let config:tokio_postgres::Config = config().expect("Error configure");
    let mgr_config = ManagerConfig {
        recycling_method: RecyclingMethod::Fast
    };
    let mgr:deadpool_postgres::Manager = Manager::from_config(config, NoTls, mgr_config);
    let pool:deadpool_r2d2::Pool<deadpool_postgres::Manager> = 
        Pool::builder(mgr).runtime(deadpool_postgres::Runtime::Tokio1).max_size(max_size).build().unwrap();
    pool
} 

#[get("ws/")]
async fn ws_index(req: HttpRequest, stream: web::Payload,db_pool: web::Data<PgPool>) -> Result<HttpResponse, Error> {
    let client:deadpool::managed::Object<deadpool_postgres::Manager> = db_pool.get().await.unwrap();
    let resp = ws::start(MyWebSocket::new(client), &req, stream);
    resp
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> { 
    let pool:PgPool = create_pool(2);
    HttpServer::new(move|| {
        App::new()
            .app_data(web::Data::new(pool.clone()))
            .wrap( middleware::DefaultHeaders::new().header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"))
            .service(ws_index)
            .wrap(middleware::Logger::default())
    })
    .workers(2)
    .bind(("0.0.0.0", 4011))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

Console:

```
error[E0728]: `await` is only allowed inside `async` functions and blocks
   --> src/test_db.rs:89:33
    |
67  | /     fn handle(&mut self, msg: Result<ws::Message, ws::ProtocolError>, ctx: &mut Self::Context) {
68  | |         
69  | |         
70  | |         match msg {
...   |
89  | |                      let stmt = self.db.prepare_cached("SELECT 1 + $1").await.unwrap();
    | |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ only allowed inside `async` functions and blocks
...   |
156 | |         }
157 | |     }
    | |_____- this is not `async`

error[E0728]: `await` is only allowed inside `async` functions and blocks
   --> src/test_db.rs:90:33
    |
67  | /     fn handle(&mut self, msg: Result<ws::Message, ws::ProtocolError>, ctx: &mut Self::Context) {
68  | |         
69  | |         
70  | |         match msg {
...   |
90  | |                      let rows = self.db.query(&stmt, &[&3]).await.unwrap();
    | |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ only allowed inside `async` functions and blocks
...   |
156 | |         }
157 | |     }
    | |_____- this is not `async`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [WebsocketContext::spawn](https://actix.rs/actix-web/actix_web_actors/ws/struct.WebsocketContext.html)

```
let db = self.db.clone();
let fut = async move {
   let stmt = db.prepare_cached("SELECT 1 + $1").await.unwrap();
   let rows = db.query(&stmt, &[&3]).await.unwrap();
   let value: i32 = rows[0].get(0);
};
let fut = actix::fut::wrap_future::<_, Self>(fut);
ctx.spawn(fut);
```

On the question in the comment:

> How to send back the result of the database operation? Use Shared
> State or Channels?

The problem you are facing is you cant move `ctx`.
A simple approach is to get the [address](https://actix.rs/actix/src/actix/actor.rs.html#274) of the actor from `ctx` which is clone and you can move it.
This approach requires an extra struct and an implementation of [Handler](https://actix.rs/actix/actix/trait.Handler.html).

```
struct WsMessage(String)

impl Handler<WsMessage> for MyWebSocket {
    type Result = ();

    fn handle(&mut self, msg: WsMessage, ctx: &mut Context<Self>) -> Self::Result {
        ctx.text(msg.0);
    }
}
```

So now you can do:

```
let db = self.db.clone();
let addr = ctx.addess();
let fut = async move {
   let stmt = db.prepare_cached("SELECT 1 + $1").await.unwrap();
   let rows = db.query(&stmt, &[&3]).await.unwrap();
   let value: i32 = rows[0].get(0);
   addr.send(WsMessage(String::from(value))).await.unwrap();
};
let fut = actix::fut::wrap_future::<_, Self>(fut);
ctx.spawn(fut);
```

*Edit*

Come to think of it, the above approach is a little too much.

Having a look at [ActorFuture](https://docs.rs/actix/latest/actix/fut/future/trait.ActorFuture.html) you should be able to do:

```
let db = self.db.clone();

let fut = async move {
   let stmt = db.prepare_cached("SELECT 1 + $1").await.unwrap();
   let rows = db.query(&stmt, &[&3]).await.unwrap();
   let value: i32 = rows[0].get(0);
   value
};
let fut = actix::fut::wrap_future::<_, Self>(fut);
let fut = fut.map(|result, actor, ctx| {
   ctx.text(result.to_string());
});
ctx.spawn(fut)
```

Comment: How to send back the result of the database operation? Use Shared State or Channels?

Comment: @Jeka see updates.

Comment: Your answer helped me figure it out, thanks

Comment: Good, remember to pick it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible but you can use the [tokio spawn task method](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/fn.spawn.html) and inside the closure you use async await.

Something like this.

```
tokio::spawn(async move {
    let stmt = self.db.prepare_cached("SELECT 1 + $1").await.unwrap();
    let rows = self.db.query(&stmt, &[&3]).await.unwrap();
    let value: i32 = rows[0].get(0);
    ctx.text(format!("{}",value));
});
```

Comment: Error: only allowed inside `async` functions and blocks
   this is not `async`

Comment: Please read the examples first. This was just a simple example. If you don't understand rust futures, please read some docs https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/01_getting_started/01_chapter.html.